# What is a 'group' or 'group address' as related to sockets and networking?

Tags: sockets, networking, ip-address

This one is awfully tough to Google. I found in code a structure like this:

```
  socket_info_a {
    address: "206.xxx.xxx.xx"
    group: "10.13.xxx.0/0"
    port: "7000"
    username: "foo"
    password: "bar"
  }
```

The x's all had actual numbers.

What is the group portion and why is it there?

Comment: It appears to be a misnomer for 'subnet'. I don't see why it needs to be there: you don't need it to create a socket or do anything with it. One would expect something labellled 'group' to have something to do with multicast, but this is not a valid multicast group address, and what the `/0` is doing there is anybody's guess. Does it work?

Comment: Yeah just the address and port works for a telnet. I think the group is just junk. Address is a TCP address. I think you must be right and it's some multicast group or subnet that was copy/pasted into this entry.